# Zoom to Feature hotkey in ArcMap Table View

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, attribute-table, customize-mode

In ArcMap 10 table view, is there a way to set up a hotkey that when a feature is selected, pressing say "z" is equivalent to right-click-->Zoom To?

I would like to be able to highlight a record and just press "z" to zoom to the feature, "p" to pan to the feature and keep the same zoom, etc.  It seems simple enough, but I cannot seem to find a place to set up this function.

Am I missing something simple? I just want to replicate the function shown below without the 2 additional mouse clicks.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are preset shortcuts, but I don't now how to change them.  For Zoom To Selected Feature, the hotkey is [**CTRL**] + [**SHIFT**] + [**=**]

Read the ArcGIS Help @ [Keyboard shortcuts for working with tables](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s00000006000000.htm), for other keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 5):

`Ctrl-Enter` will take you to the next line and select it. Using `Ctrl-N` or `Ctrl-Shift-=` will zoom to the selected row. Not too bad.

More links on hotkeys:

- [Zoom to Feature hotkey in ArcMap Table View](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15749/zoom-to-feature-hotkey-in-arcmap-table-view)
- [“NEXT” shortcut - Attribute Table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207586/next-shortcut-attribute-table)

However, you have to activate the attribute table panel by clicking somewhere inside it if you have been navigating around the map as you will lose the focus.

You can customize the shortcuts using the [Customize window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/get-started/customizing-the-ui/about-configuring-the-user-interface.htm).

There is no single command for jumping to the next record and zooming to it. You can of course create an own Python add-in or a button tool and assign it an own shortcut. You would need to access the layer programmatically, find out the next row, select it and do zooming.

Answer (score 3):

You can double click a record to zoom to

or you can

Use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/) to write a small script

for example:

```
`::^+=
```

pressing the "`" key would give you [CTRL] + [SHIFT] + [=] For Zoom To Selected Feature

```
`::^n
```

pressing the "`" key would give you [CTRL] + [p] For Pan To Selected Feature

What I commonly use:

This script is Content Aware so that the script runs only when the ArcMap window is open. It moves one record down in the table then pan's to that location.

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
#IfWinActive ArcMap
SetKeyDelay,25,25 
`::
Send {down}
Sleep, 25 
Send ^n
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought you might be able to add another button that runs the Zoom To Selection function, and give the button a keyboard shortcut like &Zoom in the name.  But it doesn't look like you can add buttons to the table view toolbar (never knew that).

However, if you double-click on the selection button (grey box on the left) of a row, it zooms to that feature on the map.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make a small change to have the great answer from Tristan Forward work (ESRI must have changed the pan to feature hot key in the past few years - from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>)

Using AutoHotKey:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
#IfWinActive ArcMap
SetKeyDelay,25,25 
`::
Send {down}
Sleep, 25 
Send ^n
Return
```

Works great for accuracy assessments in ArcGIS - just press the <kbd>`</kbd> key to pan to the next feature in an attribute table.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy fix.

You can go to customize --> customize mode --> keyboard --> layer category --> pan to selected feature command --> and assign it a new shortcut key!

[image: Pan to selected features keyboard shortcut]

Answer (score 1):

To [image] **any** feature press `Alt` button and double click on the tiny box in the left side of the attribute table.

To [image] **any** feature press `Ctrl` button and double click on the tiny box in the left side of the attribute table.

[image]

To [image] **the selected** feature press `Ctrl` + `=` (or `Ctrl` + `+`) buttons.

To [image] **the selected** feature press `Ctrl` + `N` buttons.

Tested in ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some tests and readings i have found a way for what i was looking using the keyboard shortcuts: First step, would be **Ctrl**  + **Enter** (this will take you to the next raw selection) Secondly, **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **=** which will zoom to the selected raw. The next challenge would be to finalize this with two keys.