# Changing/adding keyboard shortcuts in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, customize-mode

How can I change or add keyboard shortcuts in ArcMap?

I have tried Customize --> Customize mode --> Commands --> Keyboard. However, this does not seem to actually work. I can add shortcuts and link them, but nothing happens when I use them even though they seems to be saved (my created shortcut still shows up after restarting Arcmap).

I'm not using English keyboard layout so, for example, I can't use the [Ctrl] + [Shift] + [=] for *Zoom to selected features*, since I need Shift to even get a =. It would be really useful to be able to change or add alternative shortcuts for the tools I use regularly.

Does anyone know how? Preferably something within Arcmap, but if it comes down to writing an AutoHotkey script that'll work too if you can give me some hints.

There are a few questions relating to [shortcuts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15749/zoom-to-feature-hotkey-in-arcmap-table-view/16651#16651) already, but none that I found is giving me a useful answer. I have also looked at all the lists of shortcuts that's been implemented, both on ArcGIS Resources Online and [this very useful pdf](http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-desktop-tips.pdf). No hints on how to change the shortcuts though.

COMMENT:
If the shortcut includes [ALT GR] it doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: The customization of a shortcut key only seems to work with the incorporation of the ALT-key. I tried to customize a shortcut key for Pause Labeling using SHIFT + any key and nothing worked. Then I tried ALT + any key and they all took.

Comment: True! Works only with ALT + key

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to go to Customize> Customize Mode on the Menu bar, in ArcMap.

Once the Customize dialog appears, click on the keyboard button.

For more details, have a look at this help article: [Assigning a shortcut key](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00v00000000v000000)

Comment: Asker has not referenced the online help in the question so that's the first place I would look too.

Comment: As stated in the question, I have already tried the steps mentioned there. Those maybe 8-10 different shortcuts I've tried to add this far have not worked (and they were not previously assigned to other things). However, now I tried again with another combination and that did work. Maybe I can't use some keys? Anyway, I'll consider this topic closed since I actually got some of it working now.

Comment: Some shortcut keys are hard-coded in the software CTRL+C CTRL+V are as they are default on many applications for copy and paste.

Comment: Some of my combinations involved ALT + CTRL (= ALT GR), which apparently did not work.