# "NEXT" shortcut - Attribute Table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I am cross-checking an attribute table and clicking on features one-by-one. Is there a tool or key to jump to the next feature (by feature ID), instead of having to click in the gray cell to the left of a record, like a "next" shortcut?

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you stay within the attribute table, your best shortcut would be clicking `Ctrl+Enter` which will move cursor to the next row and select it. Clicking `Ctrl+N` will zoom to the selected row.

However, you have to activate the attribute table panel by clicking somewhere inside it if you have been navigating around the map as you will lose the focus.

More shortcuts for ArcMap are [here](http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-desktop-tips.pdf) and [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/keyboard-shortcuts-in-arcmap.htm).

Comment: Yes, that's is really what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can browse rows using the 'Move to the next record' arrow under the attribute table:

[image]

But the record won't be selected (highlighted in blue).